# slow query log includes even queries that are fast because it includes time spent waiting for lock

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

is there a way to exclude the time spent waiting for the lock so I can see only the queries that are actually expensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slow query log does not count the lock time. It only logs a query if the execution time is at least as great as `long_query_time` in seconds.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html says:

> The time to acquire the initial locks is not counted as execution time.

You may have other options enabled that make queries logged even if they are quick. For example [log_queries_not_using_indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_queries_not_using_indexes).

Comment: the slow log does say 10 seconds in other words an actual long time, but I tested it with `lock table xyz write; <waited for 10 sec> unlock table xyz`   
If there's no way to tell if the delay was due to waiting for a lock vs the time the actual query takes to run I guess I will have to do detective work when I review the log, i.e. if a bunch of queries have timestamps bunched together then probably the first query in that series is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have

```
log_queries_not_using_indexes = ON
```

I recommend `OFF`

More tips: [*SlowLog*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)